# I want to open and minimize the notepad file by clicking the one button using visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I want to open and minimize the notepad file clicking the one button using visual basic i.e ...In the first click of the button -i want to open the notepad file & again pressimg the same button second time i want to minimize the Same notepad file

Comment: You want what? Try to refraise to a question with a clear list of things you want to do.

Comment: I want to minimize & Maximize the notepad by pressing the button in visualbasic2015

Comment: Which button in VB is it that you want to press? Is there any code or configuration to this, or is it just because you cannot find the button?

Answer (score 0):

```
      HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Notepad");
        if (hwnd != 0)
        {
            ShowWindowAsync(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
            ui.label->setText("Window found");
        }
        else
        {
            ui.label->setText("Window not found");
        }
```

Comment: This answer might benefit from adding some description to the code.